# how can i get a isolate transaction on EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jta

I have the following EJB session bean:

```
@Stateless
public class FacadeBean implements FacadeBeanRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ejercicio7PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void insertar(final long id) {
        Record r = new Record();
        r.setId(id);
        em.persist(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertarTres(final long id1, final long id2, final long id3) {
        Logger.getLogger(FacadeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Insertando registros");
        insertar(id1);
        insertar(id2);
        insertar(id3);
    }

}
```

And the Record entity is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Record implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record{" + "id=" + id + '}';
    }

}
```

I am calling the remote method on standalone java application for insert three numbers:

```
 ejb.insertarTres(1l, 2l, 3l);
```

Now, I want that when I call again the remote method with the following numbers:

```
ejb.insertarTres(4l, 5l, 3l);
```

The numbers 4 and 5 are saved even if an exception occurs by number 3.

I tried to set the insert method with

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

but it is not working for my

Comment: Whoops forgot to add something to that previous comment, I mean calling it separately wherever you are calling insertarTres().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does not commit transaction of Requires\_New?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487285/why-does-not-commit-transaction-of-requires-new)

Comment: You need to get the reference to the EJB because only calling the method won't apply the proper transactional context. See the suggested answer in  @Gimby 's link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `sessionContext.getBusinessObject (FacadeBeanLocal.class);`
To get another instance of the bean to apply `REQUIRE_NEW`.

```
@Stateless
public class FacadeBean implements FacadeBeanRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ejercicio7PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    private FacadeBeanLocal local;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
      local = sessionContext.getBusinessObject(FacadeBeanLocal.class);
     }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertar(final long id) {
        Record r = new Record();
        r.setId(id);
        em.persist(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertarTres(final long id1, final long id2, final long id3) {
        Logger.getLogger(FacadeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Insertando registros");
        local.insertar(id1);
        local.insertar(id2);
        local.insertar(id3);
    }

}
```